# Customization of page turning script turn.js (javascript)

Tags: javascript, html

I'm looking at this book pages turning script:
[www.turnjs.com/#samples/magazine1](http://www.turnjs.com/#samples/magazine1)
There are many options for customization, however it seems there isn't an option for what I want to do.

The way it is now, in order to turn a page, you have to hover somewhere near the corners.
Only then the page corner turns and you somehow guess that by clicking you can go to the next page.

What I want is to make all the area clickable; wherever the mouse hovers, inside the book, one corner or another should bend.
I know I may have to edit the code directly somewhere, but I couldn't find the place although I tried.
It seems all **CSS** for page turning is inside **turn.js** file

If somebody can find the code line to be edited, please let me know.
Thanks

Comment: why not to use Method: next from their docs for this purposes?

Answer (score 0):

The jquery hover will give you the answer for this. Try include this code in your document ready function.

```
$(".turn-page").hover(function() {
       $(this).css({"transform": "rotate(-45deg) translate3d(262px, -263px, 0px)"});
       $(this).parent().css({"transform": "translate3d(-633px, 68px, 0px) rotate(45deg)"});
    });
```

Note: This is for testing purpose only. Remove the lines in hover function and add your codes.

Comment: To be more precise, I'm looking for the code line where the size of the corner is defined.  It could be in the library, I don't know why I can't find it..

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't seem to to the tweak.
I could find the  cornerSize:100 in the turn.min.js file,
but even if I change it to 200 or 300, for some reason the situation on the page doesn't change- the click-able size stays the same.
Why is that so....?